# Truncate the 2nd occurence of a substring in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string-function

I have a `SELECT` query that contains a `CASE` expression.
I have a 'Total' column with the text 'GrandTotalGroupTotal'.
There is a second column with the text 'GrandTotalGroup'.
To sum the rows in the column 'GrandTotalGroup' and put the row, 'GrandTotalGroupTotal' row, I identify the correct rows in a CASE statement as shown below.

I need to truncate the last 'Total' from the column value.
This SELECT statement works.  Bu I would like to remove the hard-coded value **GrandTotalGroup** if possible.

```
SELECT SUG3.LineOrder AS SNo, 
       CASE WHEN (Visits IS NULL) 
            THEN (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CTE3.Visits, 0)) 
                  FROM CTE3 
                  WHERE CTE3.GroupSetName = 'GrandTotalGroup') 
            ELSE ISNULL(Visits, 0) END AS Visits 
FROM  UDSStaffUtilizationGroups SUG3 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE3 ON CTE3.UDSStaffGroupID = SUG3.UDSStaffGroupID
GROUP BY SUG3.LineOrder, SUG3.GroupSetName, SUG3.GroupTotalName, CTE3.Visits
```

Is there any way to use string functions to change:
**GrandTotalGroupTotal** to **GrandTotalGroup**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('GrandTotalGroupTotal', 1, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create function Replace2ndOccurance(@str varchar(500),@strTrunc varchar(100))
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
Return Replace(STUFF(STUFF(@str,patindex('%'+@strTrunc+'%',@str),len  (@strTrunc), '-'),patindex('%'+@strTrunc+'%',STUFF(@str,patindex('%'+@strTrunc+'%',@str),len(@strTrunc), '-')),len(@strTrunc),''),'-',@strTrunc)    
end
select dbo.Replace2ndOccurance('GrandTotalGroupTotal','Total')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this.